# What machine learning technique can help generate spectrum line profiles?

Tags: computational-physics, spectroscopy, sun, software, data-analysis

I'm trying to work with Calcium-K line profiles from the Sun.

Image for reference. Please ignore the labels on the image and note that my profiles are not in image format (more info below).

[image: Calcium-K line profile]

I have over 1500 profiles like these for various latitudes and dates. The profiles are saved as 2D numpy arrays, where each array has two rows: the first row contains the wavelength values, and the second row contains the intensity values. So, plotting against each other, we get the profiles as shown above.

I would like to use an ML model to train latitude and time with line profiles. So, given future date and latitude, the model generates a possible line profile.

I'm stuck with how I can map latitude and time with the line profiles. If I flatten each numpy array and make a list of 1D numpy arrays, ANN, LSTM, and CNN models totally fail and show garbage. Random Forest, XGBoost, and KNN don't fare well either.

What algorithm can I use to solve this? And more importantly, how do I retain line profile info (that is lost if flattened) while training?

Any pointers would help.

Comment: Data Science may help. This really isn't a physics question.

Comment: For reference, Jon is talking about our sister site, [datascience.se] .

Comment: @JonCuster, yes, I figured as much and posted there as well. I just wanted to see if anyone in the physics community here has attempted this. Ultimately, whatever I get from it, I will have to understand the physics of it, so. But thanks nonetheless.

Comment: *...I will have to understand the physics of it...* What physics? You're asking about methods of storing information for use in a program/function which is purely CS.

Comment: @KyleKanos, I'm referring to what I get after I'm done training the model and forecasting with it. My thinking was that since many physicists have started using ML more these days, I could check if anyone has worked on anything similar.